# Error in creating a folder using Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am using Storage Access Framework and want to create a folder (location choosed by user through file picker) but instead it is creating a file without any extension.
I am using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` for this, you can check the intent call below:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "CCM-Tele ICU");
startActivityForResult(intent, MAKE_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_ID);
```

But instead of folder it is creating this:
[image: bin file]

I have tried creating files and it works fine but unfortunately, folder is not being created.

Comment: ` (location choosed by user through file picker)` Do you mean 'by folder picker'?

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE instead.

Comment: If I use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and the user selects lets say Downloads folder then I will get acces to all contents of Downloads folder too. I was planning to create a folder and persist only it's access permission and not the Downloads folder. Any suggestion?

Comment: The user can first create your folder in Download folder and then select it. Or in any other folder. Further if the user selects a folder you can create your own folder in it.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I will do that for now.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem of directory creation so answering my own question maybe it will help someone in future.

The Mime type that I was using is incorrect. So change it to: `DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR`

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType(DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "CCM-Tele ICU");
startActivityForResult(intent, MAKE_DIRECTORY_REQUEST_ID);
```

But it's useless as I can't use it to store things afterwards using SAF. So it's better to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` instead

Comment: Yeah, saw that. Just in case someone wants to.